# I get an 'object is not callable' error when I try to split a list item

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a web scraper and I get an error when I try to split a list item in order to parse information out of the line. I'm using BeautifulSoup and have imported the appropriate libraries. My code is as follows and works up until the line with the arrows.

```
for item in h_soup.findAll('tbody'):
  h_item = item.findAll('a', class_='email')
  length = len(h_item)
  for i in range(length):
    #print(h_item[i])
    h_email = h_item[i].split(' ')[4]    <<<This is where my error occurs.
    h_email = h_email.split('\"')[0]
    print(h_email)
```

I want to split the resulting list items on the spaces and take index 4 as a new string. I then want to split that string on a " and make the the final string to print. I get an error when I try to split the string the first time. I'm not sure if it is because I'm indexing a variable for my list item to be split.

Comment: Maybe you can debug it first? You can see the content of h_item[i] and then you will know if it can be split into an array that contains  at least 5 elements.

Comment: I tried that. The commented out print(h_item[i]) at the beginning of the second for loop works and prints each list item correctly. When I try to split and take the fourth indexed string that should result is where I get the error. I tried removing the [4] and print the resulting list of strings but I still get an error from the same line.

Comment: so can you paste the content of h_item[i] ?

Comment: <a class="email icon-mail" href="mailto: rep.jason.zachary@capitol.tn.gov"></a> This is an example of the lines that are created.

Comment: what is the error log?  your code seems ok when h_item[i] is the content you pasted. Or you can replace it with  h_email = h_item[i].split('mailto:')[1].strip()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    h_email = h_item[i].split(' ')[4]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: h_email = h_item[i][h_item[i].index("mailto:") + 8 : h_item[4].rindex('"')]   can help you do it in one step

Comment: 'NoneType' object is not callable   means the `h_item[i]` is None, not the one you pasted before.

Comment: Not sure how what to do in that case. If I comment out the last three lines and add the print(h_item[i]) back it prints the entire list of items I need to split.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, you use the `BeautifulSoup`，and the `h_item[i]` has the type  `bs4.element.Tag` , it can not use `split` directly, you should convert to string and then it will be ok.  Code here:

```py
for item in h_soup.findAll('tbody'):
  h_item = item.findAll('a', class_='email')
  length = len(h_item)
  for i in range(length):
    #print(h_item[i])
    h_email = str(h_item[i]).split(' ')[4]    <<<use str to conver to string
    h_email = h_email.split('\"')[0]
    print(h_email)
```

Note: when you  use `print(h_item[i])`, python interpreter will do the same as `print(str(h_item[i])` .